# it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element error

Tags: entity-framework

While I was trying to deal with many-to-many entities I had a mistake

> because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element

I found an answer on stack that I have to set primary key to the table, but I am not sure which column to select as primary key, because in all articles it is said that mapping table has to be table with just two foreign keys, adding third column (for example ID) just ruins this many-to-many relationship. I have 
Projects and Clients and Project_Client table where are two columns with foreign keys one to ProjectId second on ClientId. So where i have to set primary key?

My edmx:
[image]

If I add field with Id entity framework recognizes this relationship in a different way.

[image]

Comment: **adding third column (for example ID) just ruins this many-to-many relationship** That is not so true. If you do not prefer to add a third ID column as PK, you may consider using a composite primary key with those 2 columns.

Comment: Thank you! Composite primary key solved my problem.